# Visual Studio Community2015 download

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет, возникла необходимость поставить 2015 студию для проектов Core 1, инсталлы прошлые не сохранились.
По ссылке https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/older-downloads/ не получается это сделать. Вопрос конечно может простой, но решение не нахожу. Всем спасибо.
И пожалуйста дайте кто сталкивался, как она ведет с установленной 2019 студией

Comment: там же чуточку ниже есть ссылка на скачивание более старых версий https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/older-downloads/#visual-studio-2015-and-other-products

Comment: Пишет что К сожалению не удалось найти подписку

Comment: да, для старых версий нужна именно подписка. такова политика МС.

Comment: Раньше такого не было

Comment: подрезаются старые версии, то есть, версии старее определенного возраста. Поэтому "раньше такого и не было". Если есть необходимость использовать именно 2015 студию, то тогда лучше купить подписку. Если же проект не коммерческий, то дешевле может быть перевести на 2017-2019 студию.

Comment: Большое спасибо